# ssas calculated member with CASE, DIVIDE and .All members

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have some troubles with finilizing one calculation:

```
CASE
WHEN ISEMPTY( [Measures].[Base])
THEN NULL
ELSE 
DIVIDE
(([Status].[Status].CurrentMember,
[Measures].[Base]),
([Status].[Status].[All],
[Measures].[Base]))
End
```

When I intersect the result with Status - values are correct. When I use the Type filter - values are mostly correct. For "Blank" Type my values are going crazy:
[Values in %](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFd0W.png)

The should always add up to 100% - and they are but not for this Blank

Does anyone have any suggestions, Should I include sth more in my Calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Solved - the problem was with the new data in the datawarehouse